# would have been sitting/would have sat

Tags: subjunctive-mood, progressive-aspect

1. I would have been sitting there 
   if I hadn't been working.
2. I would have sat there if I hadn't been working.

Which usage is correct "would have been sitting/would have sat"?

Comment: Please don't edit to remove your question. If the answer you received helped you, just [accept it](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you really want to delete it use the _delete_ button under the question. Just don't edit it into something that is no longer a question.

Comment: If you want to delete this question, then a "delete" link will appear under it in due course. If there is only one answer with no upvotes, you will be able to delete your question. If another answer arrives, or the existing one is upvoted, you won't be able to.

Answer (score 1):

"I would have been sitting there" implies the sitting would have occurred over a period of time; "I would have sat there" implies more the process of sitting down (source: high school English class).  "I would have been sitting there when the bell rang" has a very different meaning than "I would have sat there when the bell rang".